# Fitting image to screen and allow default zoom behavior

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, image

I want to fit an image to the viewport keeping the aspect ratio and the default zoom behavior of the browser. Basically the wanted behavior is exactly like opening a local image with Chrome or Firefox.
Here is the detail of my project :

- I have a huge Unsplash image of ratio 4896x3264
- I want to create kind of a "Where Is Waldo" game where the user has to zoom in to check every detail of the image. By default I want the image to fit the screen (in this case the height at 100% max). Then the user could zoom in/out with ctrl + scroll (or any other shortcut).
- It is displayed in an angular 9 application, the html of the component simply is :
  `<img src="../../assets/img/Background.webp"/>`
  And I access this html with my `<router-outlet>`.

So right now when navigating to this page the image is displayed with its original size 4896x3264 which is way too tall for a regular screen. With CSS I can set the height and width to fit the viewport accordingly (and center it) as follow :

```
   img {
      max-height: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
```

However, with this solution I cannot zoom in to see the detail of the image anymore. Even if I zoom to 500% the image will stay fit (on my screen at 1536 x 722).

When opening the local image in the browser (Chrome or Firefox) I obtain the exact wanted behavior :
By default (100% zoom) it fits at 1017x678. I can zoom to 4896x3264 by clicking it. And I can gradually zoom with ctrl + scroll.
When inspecting the console I see that the width and height automatically changes when I zoom in and out :
`<img style="-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;cursor: zoom-in;"src="file:///D:/Videotec/Background.webp" width="1083" height="722">`

Is there a way to get this behavior in my application ? I found a lot of topics on fitting images with css to the viewport but I couldn't find something like my project. As English is not my native language I might have poorly search the web, let me know if something similar has already been addressed.

Actual behavior screenshot : https://ibb.co/DLChrtp

Wanted default behavior screenshot : https://ibb.co/p0hLDxn

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT** :
I am not sure that I described comprehensively the wanted behavior (my vocabulary limits me). Check @NVRM answer for more details

**EDIT Workaround** :
As I didn't find something out of the box I recreated the behavior with Typescript + CSS. My idea was simply to toggle ngClass from a responsive class (max-height: 100%) to a raw class with no width and height limitations. As in my game I have to retrieve the exact position of a click I used it also with scrollTo in order to center the view on the wanted coordinates.
I had to use lifecycleHook AfterViewChecked as I needed to scroll the view after the class was toggled.
I had to use a scrolled flag (boolean), otherwise the scrollTo(x,y) was also triggered when I clicked to scrollOut.
I know it is not a clean solution (I actually have more code than below, handling other stuff like dblclick etc. so some part might not seems optimal to you) but it does exactly the wanted behavior so I'll stick to it for now.

In .html

```
<div #videotecContainer class="videotec-container">
  <img
    #videotecImage
    src="../../assets/img/Videotec.webp"
    [ngClass]="zoomed ? 'zoomedIn' : 'zoomedOut'"
    (click)="onClick($event)"
  />
</div>
```

In .ts :

```
zoomed: boolean = false;
scrolled: boolean = false;
xPosition: number;
yPosition: number;
@ViewChild("videotecImage", { static: true }) videotecImage: ElementRef;
@ViewChild("videotecContainer", { static: true }) videotecContainer: ElementRef;

onClick(event: any) {
     const coordinates = this.getPixelPositions(event);
     this.xPosition = coordinates.px - coordinates.clientWidth / 2;
     this.yPosition = coordinates.py - coordinates.clientHeight / 2;
     this.zoomImage();
 }

zoomImage() {
    if (this.zoomed && this.scrolled) this.scrolled = false;
    this.zoomed = !this.zoomed;
  }

ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.zoomed && !this.scrolled) {
      this.videotecContainer.nativeElement.scrollTo(
        this.xPosition,
        this.yPosition
      );
      this.scrolled = true;
    }

getPixelPositions(event) {
  //do some calculation based on Wolfgang Fahl answer here : 
  //questions/34867066
}
```

In .css :

```
.zoomedOut {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.zoomedIn {
  display: block;
}

#videotecImage {
  overflow: scroll;
}
   
.videotec-container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Try something around https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: @NVRM When using background-size I get the same result as I have right now. I still can't zoom in/out, the image will always stay fit to the screen at height 100%

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this is what you are after? But basically, a div background and a fixed witdh, using [a not responsive absolute unit (like px)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Lengths), is pretty much the default behavior when zooming, it zoom the image too?

Click «Full page» to see it acting with the zoom.

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/p2dQlq7.jpg");
  background-size: 500px auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: #1 Thanks for your reply. Well it's not that behavior I want. In your solution if I zoom in the image is cropped and there is no scroll bar (horizontal or vertical) to crawl around the zoomed image. The wanted behavior is exactly as if you directly open your image in the browser : https://i.imgur.com/p2dQlq7.jpg when you go there the image is fitted to your screen and your cursor turns in a magnifying glass. If you clic when cursor is "+" the image goes full size and you can scroll horizontally or vertically.

Comment: #2 If you clic when cursor is "-" this image goes back to its fitting size at 100% height. In addition to the cursor behavior you can zoom in/out by changing the browser display size by using ctrl + scroll (it goes from 25% to 500%). And this seems to be the default behavior of browsers when opening a local image, that's why I'm wondering how they handle it, is that javascript ? I can see in the console that height and width value change when zooming

Comment: #3 When I use CSS with background-image ou img it does not change values of height and width dynamically